# Magento 1.8 moved to a new server and Jquery files are not loading

Tags: php, jquery, magento, path

My Magento site version 1.8 has moved to a new server and Jquery files are not loading, I am getting a 404 Not Found error, even though the files are there. I have tried all other things like deleting the cache etc. the CSS files are working fine.

Edit: ""NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://example.com.au/skin/m/1405938595/js/prototype/prototype.js,/js/lib/ccard.js,/js/prototype/validation.js,/js/scriptaculous/builder.js,/js/scriptaculous/effects.js,/js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js,/js/scriptaculous/controls.js,/js/scriptaculous/slider.js,/js/varien/js.js,/js/varien/form.js,/js/varien/menu.js,/js/mage/translate.js,/js/mage/cookies.js,/js/iwd/all/jquery-1.10.2.min.js,/js/magestore/rewardpoints.js,/js/prototype/window.js,/js/varien/product.js,/js/varien/configurable.js,/js/calendar/calendar.js,/js/calendar/calendar-setup.js,/js/ebizmarts/autoresponders/visitedproducts.js,/skin/frontend/default/nativebox/js/jquery.min.js,/skin/frontend/base/default/js/magestore/rewardpointsrule.js"

Cause the error, other js files are loading perfectly.

Comment: is the path correct for js files ?

Comment: Yes paths are correct, it worked on the old server. CSS files are working fine Which is similar to js on path wise.

Comment: I can even access the jquery files directly via browser also, its just not loading via app.

Comment: can you show any screenshot ?

Comment: I think that's a url problem. Check the path. May that include "index.php". or file permission issue.

Comment: have you tried restoring proper permissions via ssh in magento root?

    find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
    find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

Answer (score 1):

have you tried restoring proper permissions via ssh in magento root?

for folders:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

for files:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

At last found the issue,

suhosin.get.max_value_length = 10240 updated to allow for large strings

Thanks to all.

Request URL:

http://example.com.au/skin/m/1405938595/js/prototype/prototype.js,/js/lib/ccard.js,/js/prototype/validation.js,/js/scriptaculous/builder.js,/js/scriptaculous/effects.js,/js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js,/js/scriptaculous/controls.js,/js/scriptaculous/slider.js,/js/varien/js.js,/js/varien/form.js,/js/varien/menu.js,/js/mage/translate.js,/js/mage/cookies.js,/js/iwd/all/jquery-1.10.2.min.js,/js/magestore/rewardpoints.js,/js/prototype/window.js,/js/varien/product.js,/js/varien/configurable.js,/js/c...